# LINQ returns arrays, not a collection of list object

Tags: c#, arrays, linq, list

I want Linq to return an array.
In order to plot the graph.

Here is my code

```
var orders = _uow.Orders.GetAll()
            .Where(x => x.Created > baselineDate)
            .GroupBy(x => x.Created.Day)
            .Select(c => new {Day = c.Key, Total = c.Sum(t => t.Total)})
            .ToList();
```

Now it returns this

```
[{"Day":3,"Total":9999.00},{"Day":4,"Total":9999.00},{"Day":5,"Total":9999.00}]
```

BUT I want a result of

```
{"Day":[3,4,5], "Total":[9999, 9999, 9999]}
```

this result is easier to plot the graph.

Thank you all

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
var groups = _uow.Orders.GetAll()
            .Where(x => x.Created > baselineDate)
            .GroupBy(x => x.Created.Day);

var orders = new {
    Day = groups.Select(g => g.Key).ToArray(),
    Total = groups.Select(g => g.Sum(t => t.Toal)).ToArray()
};
```

Comment: Please help me this one  [link]http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17476542/linq-group-by-and-then-display-datetime-for-dd-mmm. I can't format string. @Lee

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tried, but could be like this:

```
Orders[] orders = (your query).ToArray();
```