# LINQ group-by and then display datetime for (dd mmm)

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework, datetime, group-by

I want Linq to group by date but display in text

here is my code

```
var groups = _uow.Orders.GetAll()
            .Where(x => x.Created > baselineDate)
            .GroupBy(x => x.Created.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd"));

var orders = new
        {
            Day = groups.Select(g => g.Key).ToArray(),
            Total = groups.Select(g => g.Sum(t => t.Total)).ToArray(),
        };
```

the result is (not good to put in label of graph)

```
 {"Day": [2, 3, 4, 5], "Total": [9999.00, 9999.00, 9999.00, 9999.00] }
```

But i want this (Monthly)

```
"Day": ['Jan', Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr'], "Total": [9999.00, 9999.00, 9999.00, 9999.00] }
```

Or Daily

```
"Day": ['Jan 1', 'Jan 2', 'Jan 3', 'Jan 4'], "Total": [9999.00, 9999.00, 9999.00, 9999.00] }
```

Please advice me for DateTime.ToString() that i can play with.

Thank you all.

Answer (score 4):

Thank you all for helping. 
I found the answer.

add

```
.AsEnumerable()
```

AND

```
 .GroupBy(x => x.Created.ToString("MMM d"));
```

here is full code

```
var groups = _uow.Orders.GetAll()
            .Where(x => x.Created > baselineDate)
            .AsEnumerable()
            .GroupBy(x => x.Created.ToString("MMM d"));

        var orders = new
        {
            Day = groups.Select(g => g.Key).ToArray(),
            Total = groups.Select(g => g.Sum(t => t.Total)).ToArray(),
        };
```

Answer (score 2):

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3184121/get-month-name-from-month-number) describes how to convert a date time to the string name of the month.

EDIT: for EF, we have to pull everything into memory before doing any string logic:

```
var orders = _uow.Orders.GetAll()
    .Where(x => x.Created > baselineDate)
    // pull into memory here, since we won't be making the result set any smaller and
    // we want to use DateTime.ToString(), which EF won't compile to SQL
    .AsEnumerable()
    // this will group by the whole date. If you only want to group by part of the date,
    // (e. g. day or day, month), you could group by x => x.Date.Month or the like
    .GroupBy(x => x.Date)
    .Select(g => new {
        // or use just "MMM" for just the month
        Dates = g.Select(g => g.Key.ToString("MMM d")).ToArray(),
        Total = ...
    });
```

Comment: Yeah, I know how use ToString("MMMM") or any others stringFormat. but it doesn't work  when i used LINQ to group-by.

Comment: @riseres are you using linq to objects? Linq to SQL? EF? NHibernate?

Comment: Thank You very much. @ChaseMedallion but i got error in code.
g.**Select**(g => g.**Key**.ToString("MMM d")).ToArray()
how to fix it?

Comment: It shows this==>  ExceptionMessage":"LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'System.String ToString(System.String)' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression."

Comment: @riseres: try my updated code. I've added the necessary AsEnumerable() line for EF

Comment: @ChaseMedallion Thank you I got the solution, using AsEnumerable()

Answer (score 0):

You need to use functions that EF can understand and translate to SQL, such as [`EntityFunctions.TruncateTime`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd395596.aspx).  Here is your updated code:

```
var groups = _uow.Orders.GetAll()
            .Where(x => x.Created > baselineDate)
            .GroupBy(x => EntityFunctions.TruncateTime(x.Created));
```

Then use the string formatting just in the output, but make sure you're doing it *after* the value has been returned to .Net, using `AsEnumerable` to switch to Linq-to-Objects:

```
var orders = new
        {
            Day = groups.Select(g => g.Key)
                        .AsEnumerable()
                        .Select(x => x.ToString("MMM d"))
                        .ToArray(),
            Total = groups.Select(g => g.Sum(t => t.Total)).ToArray(),
        };
```